# Origin of Quantum Randomness

Tags: quantum-mechanics, randomness

I'm in the process of developing a Quantum Random Number Generators (QRNG) for cryptographic applications. I have a basic understanding of quantum physics from my A-Levels and some additional research that I've undertaken at undergraduate level but my field of expertise is electronic engineering, not physics.

I understand the concept of wave-particle duality and that subatomic particles exist as a wave function of possible locations described by Schrodinger's equations. This results in some level of randomness in QFT which is not present in classical mechanics.

Instinctively, I want to suggest that this randomness arises from the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principal but I'm not sure if this is truly the case.

So my question is thus, what "base" theory/paper provides for the randomness present in quantum interactions?

Comment: The answer may differ depending on what specific process you're using to generate the randomness, and may, in certain cases, be no more detailed than "It's something that we assume in the foundations of quantum mechanics that happens to explain observations". Could you elaborate on what your specific setup is?

Comment: As it stands, I'll be using one of a few methods, I'm in the process of researching and evaluating each of them. The most likely candidates are time between single photon detections from an attenuated LED source; time between radioactive decays of an alpha source; result from a beam splitter (left is 0 right is 1 for example); potentially I might end up doing something with avalanche noise from a reverse biased diode but that seems less likely. 

I was hoping there was one fundamental theory that could describe the randomness. Otherwise it will be hard to justify using the "quantum" aspect.

Comment: In order to be sure that you get random results, according to QM you need to prepare a system in some well defined state of some property and then measure a property that does not commute with it, like spins on different axis. There is no way to prove, from first principles that those results are random. They just appear to be that way.